# Tomcat in Idea. war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying this [tutoial](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12). I created new project and ran it. 
TomCat started, but then nothing happened. I can manually open in browser `http://localhost:8080` and see the TomCat home page. It means server can be started. However I can't open index.jsp. Here is my screen after start:
[screenshot](http://s6.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/11/51182d39a89228013712cd83d84e13fc.jpg)
As you can see the project is running, but no info about passed environment variables. 
No logs.

I use TomCat 7.0.27

Idea 12.1.6

on Opensuse 12.2

My tomcat HOME folder is `/usr/share/tomcat`

There was a problem: 
Idea couldn't copy conf files from /usr/share/tomcat/conf to /home/loco/.IntelliJIdea12/system/tomcat//conf.
I executed `chmod 777 *` in `/usr/share/tomcat and the problem gone.`

Also I changed the way how TomCat is started.
It was default value

```
/usr/share/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

I changed to

```
/usr/share/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
```

All other steps are done in accordance to tutorial.

Comment: i was also getting same problem on intellij idea and it got resolved after changing to tomcat_8.5 (from tomcat_9). no idea about the reason yet

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The issue happens when a script in the tomcat startup set of scripts (most commonly `setenv.sh` / `setenv.bat`) override the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable without including the original value. IDEA sets `JAVA_OPTS` to tell tomcat to listen on 1099 for JMX requests for things like status and deployments.

An example of a line from a `setenv.sh` that will break:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m"
```

the corrected version:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m"
```

The same example lines from a windows `setenv.bat` file:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m
```

and corrected:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m
```

If you only run tomcat from within IDEA, you can do as other have suggested and remove the line from your `setenv` script and put the jvm options inside the IDEA run configuration.

Comment: This is the correct answer; removing `bin/setenv.sh` just removes your own local configuration and does not explain what the problem actually is. This answer explains why and how the solution works, and why it's not necessary if you craft your `bin/setenv.sh` script properly.

Comment: How to find the setenv script?

Comment: @WendyMunmunWang:  it's in $CATALINA_HOME/bin where $CATALINA_HOME is the directory where tomcat was installed to

Comment: I use mac, and I don't have setenv.sh

Comment: @codelark, I don't understand your last paragraph. `remove the line from your setenv script and put the jvm options inside the IDEA run configuration.`

Comment: I can not understand the answer. I used `export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m"` and `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m`. it not work.

Answer (score 28):

I fixed this by removing my setenv.bat in $CATALINA_HOME/bin. Here were the settings inside:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

I didn't need these options anymore, so I just removed the file. As prule's answer says, you can move these options to the Intellij Run config. After removing the file, deployment worked fine inside IntelliJ.

**edit: For a better answer on why this works, check out [codelark's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867346/657205).** Also, using his method you can keep your setenv.sh/setenv.bat files which is useful if you don't only run your Tomcat from inside IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me too.  Looks like any setenv.sh (or setenv.bat) will cause this problem to occur.

Comment: I cannot find setenv.bat . I'm using tomcat7, where can I find it?

Comment: If you didn't make a setenv.bat then it probably doesn't exist. However it can be found in $CATALINA_HOME/bin/. Also, on Linux it will be setenv.sh.

Comment: In case you don't have the setenv.sh, sometimes you can find JAVA_OPTS inside the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh file.

Comment: Awesome! This was the issue. Please mark this as correct answer.

Comment: Hi , I also got the same error ,but I cannot find the setenv.sh(or setenv.bat) in the %CATALINA_HOME%\bin , and the catalina.bat/.sh doesn't contain this command . I just find below :   ```set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"```

Comment: Codelark has a better answer below that explains what it happening, and why simply removing `bin/setenv.sh|bat` isn't the one-and-only solution to this problem.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz You're right, Codelark has a more thorough answer. At the time I just happened to find a quick fix and didn't try to figure out the reason my fix worked. I'll edit my answer to suggest users to check out his answer below.

Comment: @ChristianWilkie There is no setenv.bat or setenv.sh in $CATALINA_HOME/bin. What should I do?

Comment: @ChristianWilkie I'm running tomcat 8.0.30 on Mac OS installed from homebrew. I don't have a setenv.sh in my $CATALINA_HOME/bin directory. What should i do?

Comment: Sorry Michael/Eidan, not sure since I haven't encountered this issue again after I applied my solution :(

Comment: @Michael did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Removing `setenv.sh` from `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` also worked for me. 
I'm running tomcat7/Ubuntu/IntelliJ 12

With `setenv.sh` in the bin folder, on startup inside IJ I see in the logs :

```
/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/catalina.sh run
[2014-07-28 02:41:39,274] Artifact TomcatDebug:war exploded: Server is not connected. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment.
Jul 28, 2014 2:41:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

odonovanj@ubuntuj:/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.52$ sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 2928
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2928/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      2928/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      2928/java
```

After removing, in the logs I see : 
    INFO: Server startup in 76 ms
    Connected to server
    [2014-07-28 02:44:35,847] Artifact TomcatDebug:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    [2014-07-28 02:44:36,512] Artifact TomcatDebug:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully

```
odonovanj@ubuntuj:/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.52$ sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 2346
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2346/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::50044                :::*                    LISTEN      2346/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      2346/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      2346/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN      2346/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::52268                :::*                    LISTEN      2346/java
```

Seems like the `setenv.sh` was overriding `$JAVA_OPTS`, interfering with JNDI running on port 1099.

Answer (score 4):

```
file->project structure->Project SDK
```

then reconfigure the SDK.

This really solved my problem.

Comment: This really helped. Btw, I did file->project structure->Project SDK and then selected the JDK instead of the intelij SDK

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand much about the theory of this, but I got the same error.  After waiting a bit I got a message saying:

Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

I found the log file it presumably meant:  "Tomcat localhost.log" and there was a stack trace there for a "NoClassDefFoundError" and  "ClassNotFoundException".  I did a refresh of Maven and a "Rebuild project" and that did the trick.

Comment: Yeah, rebuilt a project with Gradle and have it finally working, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. It works with maven for me! I lost two hours for looking for environment variable values...

Answer (score 1):

(3.2) Set JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME (required)

These variables are used to specify location of a Java Runtime Environment or of a Java Development Kit that is used to start Tomcat.

The JRE_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JRE. The JAVA_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JDK.

Using JAVA_HOME provides access to certain additional startup options that are not allowed when JRE_HOME is used.

If both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are specified, JRE_HOME is used.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had set JAVA_OPTS in catalina.bat. Removing this meant that tomcat started and deployed as expected. The JAVA_OPTS values can be set in the Intellij Run config.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Tomcat 7.0.27.
I upgraded to Tomcat 8.0.21 and it fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem when try to import a project from eclipse to IDEA.

There is no `setter.sh` in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin`. The `Project Structure` and `Run Configuration` setting in IDEA looks OK, the whole project works normally in eclipse, but show this error in IDEA.

My solution is, delete the `.idea` folder, re-import the whole project. I don't know what's the accurate cause of this problem, but is works for me.

Now the log looks like that:

```
/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run

[2015-09-22 12:40:57,906] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
XXXXXX
Connected to server
[2015-09-22 12:40:58,848] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
XXXXXX
[2015-09-22 12:41:07,862] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-09-22 12:41:07,863] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Deploy took 9,015 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to change the port number in that file:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

notice the port, default is 1099, but when use JMX, it may changed by you or someone, so, just simply change the port, that will be OK, no need to remove it from the tomcat bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

One more reason, if your tomcat path contains blank or '(', this error will also occur. Please rename your tomcat path.

Answer (score 0):

If you had changed `/etc/hosts` file, you need to add a line `localhost    YOU_USER_NAME` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the TOMCAT BIN DIRECTORY
Run on the command prompt the following command

cd Tomcat-9991\bin

**catalina.bat run**

the output I got was

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Indicating that i had a JAVA Version issue between my tomcat and the JDK I was setting this too.

I could fix it by chainging to the correct version of JDK.