# IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.3 and Tomcat 8.0.9. Cant get it to work

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to deploy a Java web application running on Tomcat. I got the book

> Professional Java for Web Applications: Featuring Websockets, Spring Framework, JPA Hibernate, and Spring Security

and I've done everything said to get IntelliJ IDEA 13 work together with Tomcat 8.0.9. I've tested the server container manually and it works great, even deploying .war files works great. However when i move on to start/debug a web application - in this case the first example form the book - from IntelliJ the application wont start. The output in the Tomcat Log doesn't say much.

Server output tells me this:

```
Connected to server
[2014-08-08 09:17:35,075] Artifact Sample-Debug-IntelliJ:war exploded: Artifact is      being deployed, please wait...
[2014-08-08 09:17:35,097] Artifact Sample-Debug-IntelliJ:war exploded: Error during  artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2014-08-08 09:17:35,098] Artifact Sample-Debug-IntelliJ:war exploded: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: L:\java-dev\java_web_apps_chapter_code\9781118656464 Full Code\Chapter 02\Sample-Debug-    IntelliJ\target\sample-debug-intellij-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT not found for the web module.
08-Aug-2014 21:17:44.671 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory L:\java-dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\webapps\manager
08-Aug-2014 21:17:44.939 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory L:\java-dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\webapps\manager has finished in 268 ms
```

Tomcat Catalina Log output this:

```
08-Aug-2014 22:56:35.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.4.8.
08-Aug-2014 22:56:35.846 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.738 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.746 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.747 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1060 ms
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.778 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.784 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
08-Aug-2014 22:56:36.785 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 38 ms
08-Aug-2014 22:56:46.785 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory L:\java-dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\webapps\manager
08-Aug-2014 22:56:47.035 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory L:\java-dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\webapps\manager has finished in 251 ms
```

I've tried on both Windows and OSX and it's the same story on both with the exact same error.

When i access `http://localhost:8080/`i can see that the server is up and running. However, the application isn't deployed.

Anyone experiencing the same error as me and/or know a solution?

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.3, Java 1.8.0_11 and Tomcat 8.0.9.

EDIT: I've also tried with IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4. Didn't make any difference.

---

### Steps taken

1. Downloaded Java 1.8.0_11, installed it and added it to environment variables.
2. Downloaded Tomcat, unpacked it and made the following changes to it (step 2-4);
   In `conf/tomcat-users.xml` i added this user:

   ```
   <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
   ```
3. In `conf/web.xml` i added the code below beneath the `org.apache.jasper.servlet.jspServlet` element

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
       <param-value>1.8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
       <param-value>1.8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param> 
       <param-name>compiler</param-name>
       <param-value>modern</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```
4. Downloaded apache-ant and added a `setenv.bat` file in the `apache-tomcat/bin` directory with the following script

   ```
   export CLASSPATH=L:/java-dev/jdk8/lib/tools.jar:L:/java-dev/apache-ant/lib/ant.jar:L:/java-dev/apache-ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
   ```
5. Started IntelliJ and added the Tomcat application server.
6. Then i imported the project and set it to use the Tomcat server that I just added.

### UPDATE: 2014-08-09 16:22

I tried to deploy a JavaEE web application that IntelliJ created itself, and that worked right away. Seems like it's something wrong with the source code that the book references.

Comment: I see this error:  `Artifact Sample-Debug-IntelliJ:war exploded: Error during  artifact deployment. See server log for details.` Did you check the logs?

Comment: Actually the error is there: `...Full Code\Chapter 02\Sample-Debug-    IntelliJ\target\sample-debug-intellij-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT not found for the web module.`

Comment: I don't know exactly which log that message has in mind, because all the logs I've checked - other then the server log that outputs the message posted above - don't mention anything about any error. Though I've only checked the logs which appear in IntelliJ which is Server, Tomcat Catalina Log, Tomcat Localhost Log, Tomcat Manager Log, Tomcat Host Manager Log and Tomcat Localhost Access Log. All logs are blank except for Server and Tomcat Catalina Log. I'll post in query what the catalina log output.

Comment: Have you tried deleting setenv.bat before running tomcat? I had a similar issue before and solved it by moving my configuration from setenv.bat to the IntelliJ run config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available/22821256#22821256

Comment: Christian Wilkie, tried that. Didn't work :-( Will try with a earlier version of Java and Tomcat, to see if that helps.

Comment: Did you download the JRE or the JDK? What is the result of `java -version`?

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem. The problem was in artifact configuration in Run/Debug Configurations. I had to remove the project artifact and readd it. The important thing is to choose Web Application: Exploded, From Modules...

You can read my [blog post](http://www.jrelease.com/2015/05/02/deployment-in-tomcat-fails-with-jmxadminexception/) that contains screenshots about this issue.

Comment: my `Web Application: Exploded` do not have  `From Modules`, how do I solve it?

Comment: @Mithril I have the same problem, have you solved the problem ??

Comment: www.jrelease.com’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with:

> File >Project Structure >Artifacts
>   In the
>   Output Layout on the right side >"Available Elements?"

right click on the available libraries ( for me it was "Spring MVC-4.2.4.RELEASE")

> Put into Lib ( actually click on the fix warning button )

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Debug Configuration" in IntelliJ IDEA and make sure that "Deploy applications configured in Tomcat" checkbox is checked as it shown on the [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346328/cannot-run-debug-jsp-page-from-within-intellij-using-tomcat-server/28346753#28346753)

Answer (score 0):

1. open the artifact config dialog (artifact > edit...)
2. check 'Show contents of elements' in the dialogs bottom section
3. highlight the 'WEB-INF' directory
4. right click on the library container (on the right pane)
5. select from context menu 'put into /WEB-INF/lib'
6. the lib folder is added in the *output layout*
7. rebuild artifact
8. restart webserver

Hope it helps.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 4]

[image: screenshot 3]