# Artifact JavaWeb: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to deploy a freshly generated Java Web App with IntelliJ-IDEA UE 2017.1, but I keep getting the following errors:

> Artifact JavaWeb: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
>
> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

I have Tomcat 9 installed, and working (tested outside IntelliJ). I also have Java 8 installed and working.

I have searched through SO for solutions, and tried the following:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452209/6996944) suggests I should set JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables to fix the issue. These are set, so not a solution for me.
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22821256/6996944) suggests I should remove a file called *setenv*. There is no such file in my HDD, so not a solution for me either.
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776493/6996944) suggests I should rebuild the project. Rebuilt several times, didn't fix it for me.
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32379498/6996944) suggests I should make sure I have the proper SDK set in my project. I do.
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867346/6996944) lastly for me, suggests that I should add JAVA_OPTS on IDEA itself `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m`. Well, apparently `MaxPermSize` got removed on Java 8, and `-Xmx1024m` solves nothing for me.

I also get this, when clicking on a browser icon (they appear when you hover over the `.jsp` file:

> Browser Error: There is no configured/running web-servers found! Please, run any web-configuration and hit the refresh button!

I'm running out of ideas. Is there anyone who tried all of these and fixed it who could give me a hand?

For reference:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Try the vanilla release Tomcat 8 version instead, don't modify any environment options passed by IntelliJ IDEA to the server.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new), attach [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and the full output from the Run console when you start Tomcat. Also attach `.idea` directory contents from the problematic project.

Comment: Just did. Thanks.

Comment: Asked for the console log and didn't get any response so far. Anyway, please check if https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171174 helps.