# Tomcat in Intellij IDEA 14 : war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, web-deployment

I find [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available), but it cannot resolve my issue.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62554', transport: 'socket'
[2015-06-09 11:15:23,088] Artifact com-XXXXXXXXX-web:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
```

[image: the $CATALINA_HOME/bin]

My Env : Tomcat7.0.59 + Intellij IDEA 14.1 + MAc Pro-64 bits

there isn't the `setEnv.bat or setEnv.sh` file , and I have not found the command like this
`set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M`.
Just the command , `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%”` ,found in `catalina.bat`, which you can check it in my [Attachments repo on github](https://github.com/FrankBian/Attachments/tree/master/tomcat).

I don't know the actual reason of this ,but it can also occasionally work after I refresh and rebuild the project via maven .

But the rebuilding is useless NOW !

How can I fix it completely ?

Thank you very much ..

Comment: seems to be old question, but have you solved this problem @Frank. Am facing the same issue too...

Answer (score 0):

> there isn't the setEnv.bat or setEnv.sh file

The setenv script is documented in RUNNING.txt. By default there is no such file - you create it by yourself.

Beware that the proper name is "setenv.sh" (lowercase).

Comment: thanks very much , but I find that describes it's optional , and I have set the  variables in ~/.bash_profile .  So I think this is not the key point