# IntelliJ 14 / Tomcat 8.0.23 - Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I already tried what was suggested in:

[Tomcat in Idea. war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available/22821256#22821256)

The creation of setenv.bat file with line

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m

did not change anything.

Project setup was made following:

https://medium.com/@jamsesso/starting-out-with-jersey-apache-tomcat-using-intellij-6338d93ffd40

Tried acessing using URL: localhost/8080/TraffiCar/hello, 404 returned

There are no other applications using the ports, 8080 and 1099

The log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2015-07-03 02:13:31,724] Artifact TraffiCar:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Aleister\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TraffiCar"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.357 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.357 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.23.0
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b15
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Aleister\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TraffiCar
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Aleister\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TraffiCar\conf\logging.properties
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\endorsed
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Aleister\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TraffiCar
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\temp
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.1.
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
03-Jul-2015 14:13:32.928 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015)
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.043 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.050 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 927 ms
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.089 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.104 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
03-Jul-2015 14:13:33.105 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 53 ms
Connected to server
[2015-07-03 02:13:33,338] Artifact TraffiCar:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2015-07-03 02:13:33,564] Artifact TraffiCar:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-07-03 02:13:33,564] Artifact TraffiCar:war exploded: Deploy took 226 milliseconds
03-Jul-2015 14:13:43.091 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\manager
03-Jul-2015 14:13:43.134 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\manager has finished in 42 ms
```