# Intellij IDEA - cannot deploy to tomcat

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

From time to time I cannot access my deployed applications when I deploy them - I'm receiving message -

```
iu-sport-ui.war (exploded): Server is not connected. Deploy is not available
```

It's weird for me, because sometimes I can deploy my apps and sometimes I cannot do that.

I tried to do exactly as in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available) But it didn't helped me.

Here is the logs - https://gist.github.com/ivanursul/c4ffaf6f69fbe8e2933c

Here is screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys, so, after few weeks of observations I realised what can be the problem. The problem was with deploying to tomcat - my services were too big, and I used tomcat instance with some predefined wars in webapps folder. So I removed all unnecessary wars, and tried it again - and everything worked fine!