# War exploded: Error during artifact deployment. Tomcat 8.5+IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure Tomcat 8.5 on Intellij Idea Ultimate.

I installed it in /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11. I'm using Ubuntu.

When I run the project I have these output:

```
`/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-02-05 02:40:12,566] Artifact Spring1:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.144 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.146 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.11.0
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-62-generic
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/marcel/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Spring1
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/marcel/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Spring1/conf/logging.properties
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.150 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/marcel/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Spring1
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/marcel/.local/share/umake/ide/idea-ultimate/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.270 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.286 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.287 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.287 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 415 ms
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.328 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.333 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.334 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 46 ms
Connected to server
[2017-02-05 02:40:13,677] Artifact Spring1:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.940 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
05-Feb-2017 14:40:13.950 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-02-05 02:40:13,964] Artifact Spring1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.329 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/host-manager
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.388 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/host-manager has finished in 58 ms
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.388 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/examples
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.609 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/examples has finished in 221 ms
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.610 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/docs
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.624 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/docs has finished in 15 ms
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.624 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/manager
05-Feb-2017 14:40:23.641 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/manager has finished in 17 ms
`
```

I'm using the following configuration in IDEA :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQMli.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE2QY.jpg

I tried to follow [Tomcat in Idea. war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available/28867346#28867346) but Tomcat 8.5 bin there's no setenv.sh .

Thanks for help.